Are questions about Human Computer Interaction (HCI) research on or off topic?
I was particularly interested in this site since I'm designing and evaluating a novel user interface for my thesis. During my design process I would like to back up design decisions with theory.
A definition of HCI:

Human-computer interaction is a discipline concerned with the design,
  evaluation and implementation of interactive computing systems for
  human use and with the study of major phenomena surrounding them.

User Experience Stack Exchange already discusses user experience, but generally there are more practical questions asked there and it's less scientific than I expect this site to be.
Which is in scope here and where to draw the line?

This discussion is also on User Experience.StackExchange

Human Computer Interaction is a cognitive science, full stop. 
There is likely some overlap similar to how questions are occasionally relevant on both Programmers.SE and DBA.SE, to me the same question could be posited to both sites and recieve great, but different answers. 
Assuming the question is asking about research or why a certain effect or behavior is seen, I think it's acceptable here. If it's asking how something should be designed it's more likely UX.SE only.
